# Node js app using mongo db without running mongo db service, like sqlite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I do not want to use SQLite in my Node js app.

Would like to use MongoDB, but don't want to have Mongo DB Service running on system.

Is there MongoDB Lite or something for node js ?

I'm not using Meteor; can I still use minimongo with my Node js app ?

Comment: have a look to this fork of minimongo https://github.com/mWater/minimongo IMO im not sure if this kind of mongo implementation has similar features to sqlite but mongo complete service isn't heavy for your system

Comment: Mongo process is not a problem, run it manually and kill it by yourself on the end of the work. What's the problem?